# Async Action Method with ActionController / AsyncActionController

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can write an Action Method in MVC using Async and Await keywords in my controller class inheriting Controller, then why/what is the purpose of AsyncController base class?

In code what is the difference between the following two approach

```
    public class FileUploadController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {...}
    }
```

vs

```
 public class FileUploadController : AsyncController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know async tasks helps to optimise pool http rquests,

> Most web developers know about ASP.NET’s request processing pipeline. An HTTP request is synchronously processed on a Thread which is grabbed from the ThreadPool. The Thread on which this request is processed is blocked from doing anything else like handling another incoming reques

[Here](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/aspnet-mvc-4-implementing-asynchronous.html) is interesing article about it, 
Maybe it will be helpfull.